# Can Joomla make auto currency to displayed after typing specific format?

Tags: types, joomla

I have seen websites that if the user wrote some specific format like this in the back-end for example :

1. Polo Shirt , 500
2. V-Neck Shirt , 500
3. Pijamas , 500
4. Polo Shirt , 750
5. Jeans , 750

Then in the front-end it will display (in table form):

**$500**

Polo Shirt

V-Neck Shirt

Pijamas

**$750**

Polo Shirt

Jeans

They will automatically divide items and price by a comma and just by typing number then it will automatically give a currency symbol.  Also the items will be ordered based on the price.

Can Joomla do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joomla can't do that by itself, but it's quite easy to implement such feature.

Anyway I'd still suggest having two separate fields in form at least for validation and type hints.

*Probably you've seen in the backend that it does't let you save the form when one of the fields is invalid and it marks the field border with red color.*

If you are after speed in filling in forms, use `tab` button.

Comment: Can you explain it more thoroughly or maybe step by step tutorial how to make that?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may parse data easily: `list($product, $price) = explode(',', 'Polo Shirt, 500');`, but it's much easier to work with 2 separate fields right at the time where users inserts data. For example you can setup the price field to be numeric only client-side using HTML5. If you are working with string of text, you have to parse it first and that's where it becomes complicated (for case when product name is OK, but price is not you'd have to prepare own validation rules)

Comment: Should I put that directly into the text editor in the article?  I'm sorry because I don't really know about php stuff.  And FYI about the user, this will only be typed by the admin.  Thank You!

Comment: You need an extension which is able to work with data: grouping and sorting (ecommerce or CCK)

Comment: can you tell me what's the name of the extension to find? Thank You

Comment: Sorry, you have to research yourself. I haven't seen extension that would allow such data entry, but it's common format when importing data from CSV files (comma separated values)